# Unable to Add Liquidity using uni swap V2 front end clone

Tags: frontend, uniswapv2, liquidity, router

I’m having error from the Uniswapv2 clone that I cloned following the below website instructions:
https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/unified-api/guides/how-to-clone-uniswapv2-frontend/

The problem I’m facing is that I tried adding liquidity in Uniswap, however when after I approve the spending and press supply, the add supply button just load one time and then stop. Nothing happens after this. It seems that I have to confirm something in my metamask but my meta mask does not have anything for confirmation.
I deployed and change contracts and networks several times, yet error still persist for days now.

Please help me.